# Reformatting object pre in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm making a private HTML app and, I want it to show text from a local txt file. I'm using this:

```html
<div class="notatki">
    <object class="content" data="C:\Users\kacpi\OneDrive\Dokumenty\lekcje\strony internetowe\4\notatki\chemia.txt">Not supported</object>
</div>
```

to insert the document but when I try to use:

```css
.notatki pre{
    color: white;
}
```

in the style file to make the text white, it just doesn't work.
EDIT: I use the `pre` tag in CSS because when I check the element in the browser it shows up as `pre`.

Comment: The problem is that it creates an external HTML file, and because of that the style definitions you added doesn't being take into consideration.

Comment: You need to render the contents of that file as HTML elements for the css to work and not just load a multiline string containing HTML. Perhaps if you convert your `.txt` file to `.html`.

Comment: converting it into .html makes it not only unformatted but also still doesnt work. thanks tho

Comment: If you look in your browser dev tools inspect facility you will see the elements with the object being within what is basically a separate embedded document. Could you describe what you actually want to happen - do you want to get the contents of that file and put them into an element in your HTML?